# Backbone view not displaying with no errors showing up

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this strange problem where my backbone view is not displaying and I am getting no errors. I have followed my previous procedures which work perfectly to the tee but noting seems to work for this view.

I am perplexed why its not working hopefully one of ye can see whats going on.

If I walk through the code the model is being fetched properly and there is data in it.

**main.js**

```
  this.absences = new AbsenceCollection({idC:id},{option: 0});
            this.absences.fetch({success: function(){

                $('#contents').html( new AbsenceListView ({model: app.absences}).render.el,id);

            }});
```

**AbsenceList.js**

```
window.AbsenceListView = Backbone.View.extend({


    tagName:'table',


    initialize:function () {

        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        var self = this;

        this.model.bind("add", function (absence) {
            $(self.el).append(new AbsenceListItemView({model:absence}).render().el);
        });
    },

    render:function (eventName) {

        _.each(this.model.models, function (absence) {
            $(this.el).append(new AbsenceListItemView({model:absence}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

window.AbsenceListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:"tr",

    initialize:function () {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('absence-table'));
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },


    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});
```

**Absence Model**

```
window.Absence = Backbone.Model.extend({

        //SIMS/resource/class datatables http//localhost:8080

   baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/SIMS/resource/absence",
            url: function() {
                return this.baseURL + '/' + idClass + '/' + option;



            },    

             initialize: function(attributes, options){

          option = options.option;
          idClass = attributes.idC;

      },



    defaults: {

                  "week":"",
                  "StudentidStudent":"",
                  "classidClass":"",
                  "monday":"",
                  "tuesday":"",
                  "wednesday":"",
                  "thursday":"",
                  "friday":""

      }



});

window.AbsenceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Absence,

         baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/SIMS/resource/absence",
            url: function() {
                return this.baseURL + '/' + idClass + '/' + option;



            },


                  initialize: function(attributes, options){
          option = options.option;
          idClass = attributes.idC;

      }




});
```

Comment: `.render.el` should be `.render().el` in main.js.

Comment: Thank you, I have been staring at this code to long to notice anything.   Really fustrating that this dosent raise an error. Please add as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Alex got it. `.render` is a reference to a function. `.render.el` would result in `undefined` but no error. `$(..).html(undefined)` would just erase the contents. JSHint may have helped catch this. http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: You could also try turning on strict mode in your JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render is a function which returns this, so you are chaining correctly, just replace render.el with

```
render().el
```